# Powershell request Bearer token from api call

Tags: powershell, bearer-token

I have a script in Powershell where I request a Bearer token to do some stuff later.
The problem is, I always get a Bad-Request (400)

In the body, I provide the clientId and ClientSecret, but it looks like the call is not using my credentials

Can someone help me please?

I searched a lot on the internet and tried some different things, but nothing worked so far.

```bsh
function GetBearer ([string]$clientId, [string]$clientSecret) {
    $tokenEndpoint = 'http://web-scsecur-sso.appliarmony.net/TokenService/connect/token'
    $body = @{  
        'client_id'= $clientId
        'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
        'client_secret' = $clientSecret
    }       

    $params = @{
        Body = $Body
        Method = 'Post'
        Uri = $tokenEndpoint
    }   

    $token = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://web-scsecur-sso.appliarmony.net/TokenService/connect/token" -Method POST -Body $body  -ContentType  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 

    Return "Bearer " + ($token.access_token).ToString()
}
```

The output should be a Bearer token, but so far I received nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTTP 400 (Bad Request) response from a web server is telling you that it doesn't like something about your request and is refusing to do anything. What's wrong could be any number of things (typo in body params, wrong url, invalid/expired secret, etc).

Some APIs will be more verbose in their 400 responses to give you a better idea of exactly what's wrong. But not always. And even if there is a response body, it may not be shown by default depending on your PowerShell version (6 and above should show it).

If you're on PowerShell 5.1 or earlier, here's a way to get the response body if it exists.

```bsh
try {
    $token = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://web-scsecur-sso.appliarmony.net/TokenService/connect/token" -Method POST -Body $body  -ContentType  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
} catch {
    $response = $_.Exception.Response
    if ($response.StatusCode -eq [System.Net.HttpStatusCode]::BadRequest) {
        $stream = $response.GetResponseStream()
        $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($stream)
        $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
        $reader.DiscardBufferedData()
        $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd();
        Write-Warning $responseBody
    }
    throw
}
```

Comment: Thanks, because of the response I now see that I've got a warning 'invalid_scope', I am one step closer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the try-catch I found the answer.

The first response was Invalid_client

Second response Invalid_scope, this was a bit harder to find a solution for, I just had to insert an extra property, scope, to my body.